# Refactoring rspec with let

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.
How can I refactor this code below with `let` instead of using instance variables?

```
describe User do    

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end    

  subject { @user }    

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }    

  it { should be_valid }    

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

I tried to refactor the code on my own but failed.

```
describe User do
  let(:user) { User.new(name: "Example User", email:"foo@example.com") }    

  subject { user }    

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }  

  it { should be_valid }    

  describe "when name is not present" do
    # ???
    let(:name) { " " } 
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "when name is not present" example group, this is sufficient:

```
describe "when name is not present" do
  before { subject.name = '' }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

From the code you posted alone, there's no added value for setting `:name` with `let()`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've just found the way to do: `before { user.name = " " }` but didin't know I can use `subject.name`, thanks!:)

Comment: Yeah, more sense to use `subject` since it's specifically what you're testing with in `should_not be_valid`. :-)